How/Where does PyTorch max documentation show that you can pass in 2 tensors for comparison?
I am learning pytorch and deep learning. The documentation for torch.max doesn't make sense in that it looks like we can compare 2 tensors but I don't see where in the documentation I could have determined this.
I had this code at first where I wanted to check ReLU values against the maximum. I thought that 0 could be broadcast for and h1.shape=torch.Size([10000, 128]).
h1 = torch.max(h1, 0)
y = h1 @ W2 + b2

However, I got this error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'torch.return_types.max' and 'Tensor'
I got to fix this when I changed the max equation to use a tensor instead of 0.
h1 = torch.max(h1, torch.tensor(0))
y = h1 @ W2 + b2

1. Why does this fix the error?
This is when I checked the documentation again and realized that there is nothing mentions a collection like a tuple or list for multiple tensors or even a *input for iterable unpacking.
Here are the 2 versions:
1st torch.max version:

torch.max(input) → Tensor Returns the maximum value of all elements in
the input tensor.
Warning
This function produces deterministic (sub)gradients unlike max(dim=0)

2nd version of torch.max

torch.max(input, dim, keepdim=False, *, out=None) Returns a namedtuple
(values, indices) where values is the maximum value of each row of the
input tensor in the given dimension dim. And indices is the index
location of each maximum value found (argmax).
If keepdim is True, the output tensors are of the same size as input
except in the dimension dim where they are of size 1. Otherwise, dim
is squeezed (see torch.squeeze()), resulting in the output tensors
having 1 fewer dimension than input.

2. What is tensor(0) according to this documentation?

I'm not an expert in pytorch, but when you do torch.max(h1, 0) I think it's treating 0 as the dimension you want to reduce on, it's same as torch.max(h1, dim=0). In contrast when you call torch.max(h1, tensor(0)) it's doing elementwise comparison which is what you want.

Yes, the latter is what I want but does the documentation reveal this in any way? I understand that you are not a PyTorch expert.

Check the bottom of the documentation page you linked where it says:
torch.max(input, other, *, out=None) → Tensor

See torch.maximum().

When the second argument is a tensor, torch.max computes torch.maximum

The indentation of the documentation is misleading. I didn't see that last line. It didn't seem like it was at the same level.
